# Angular 5 application takes a long time to load for first time users, I need help to speed it up

Tags: performance, angular5

Angular 5 application where it take more time while first time loading application at any server and for more information I use AOT compiler for production.

tsconfig.json

```
 {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There are some ways by which you can optimize the first load.**

**1: Build Options**

> ng build --prod

**2: Lazy Loading**

You should refactor your application to use lazyLoading. In Angular lazyload is the approach to load modules when needed. So less code will be loaded on the first load and then when the user moves to other routes required chunk files will be loaded.
[find the official doc for lazyLoading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

**3: Import what you need**

> Import only needed functions. e.g lodash

Instead of

**import * as _ from "lodash";**

Use

> import { toLower } from “lodash”;

**4: CDN**

Make use of CDN(CloudFront/s3) to load your assets(static files).

**5: Dynamic Script loading**

Do not load all script in the index.html file. Instead, load dynamically in
individually component when needed

Comment: I applied number one and got result :)

Comment: The ng build command with the --prod meta-flag (ng build --prod) compiles with AOT by default.